# How to save aggregation change?

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, aggregate

I am executing the following:

```
db.emails.aggregate(
 [
    {$addFields : {arr : {$objectToArray : "$$ROOT"}}}, 
    {$project : { pass : {$slice : ["$arr.v", 1, 20 ] }}}
]
).pretty()
```

When I exit the session / shell, the changes are not saved.

Can someone please direct me on how to apply this modification to the entire collection and save it?

Comment: Use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate and update MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229566/aggregate-and-update-mongodb)

Comment: @Veeram It's not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

looks like continuation of [How to merge multiple fields in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48374158/3344829)

you can `$out` to new collection,check data,rename to old collection name dropping old data

```
db.emails.aggregate(
 [
    {$addFields : {arr : {$objectToArray : "$$ROOT"}}}, 
    {$project : { pass : {$slice : ["$arr.v", 1, 20 ] }}},
    {$out : "new_emails"} // out to new collection
]
).pretty()

db.new_emails.renameCollection('emails', true); // rename collection, true - dropTarget
```